# How do I convert this, "2021-07-05T22:26:51.159Z" to Date() with swift

Tags: ios, date, datetime, swift5

I think this is an ISO8601 formatted timestamp.
2021-07-05T22:26:51.159Z
I'm trying to convert it with ISO8601DateFormatter() in swift 5.
Here's what I've tried:

```
let dateFormatter = ISO8601DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.formatOptions = .withFullDate
//ISO8601DateFormatter().formatOptions = .withFractionalSeconds
let d = "2021-07-05T22:26:51.159Z" 
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: d)
```

The result:
date = 2021-07-05 00:00:00 UTC
The day is correct, the time is not. I've tried to set the .withFractionalSeconds option. Didn't help.

How should I convert this format?

Comment: `dateFormatter.formatOptions = [.withFullDate, .withFullTime, .withFractionalSeconds]`? The tip is to instead do `print(dateFormatter.string(from: Date()))` which would show you what's the formatter "expects". Then you'll see what's really interpreted or not, and you'll see what's missing.

Comment: @Larme `[.withInternetDateTime, .withFractionalSeconds]` works too.

Comment: Yeah, those worked. I didn't know how to set the options. I added "dateFormatter.formatOptions.insert(.withFractionalSeconds)" and it work fine. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use standard date formatter to achieve this:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")
dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(secondsFromGMT: 0)
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ"
let date = dateFormatter.date(from: d)
print(date)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I tried something similar, but would never have figured out "SSS.ZZZZZ"